# R: How can I use the package Rcrawler to do JSON parsing in parallel?

Tags: json, r, rcrawler

I just came across this powerful R package but unfortunately haven't been able to find out how to parse a list of urls in parallel where the response is in JSON.

As a simple example, suppose I have a list of cities (in Switzerland):

```
list_cities <- c("Winterthur", "Bern", "Basel", "Lausanne", "Lugano")
```

In a next step I'd like to find public transport connections to the city of Zurich for each of the listed cities. I can use the following transport api to query public timetable data:

```
https://transport.opendata.ch
```

Using the httr package, I can make a request for each city as follows:

```
for (city in list_cities) {
   r <- GET(paste0("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=", city, "&to=Zurich&limit=1&fields[]=connections/duration"))
   cont <- content(r, as = "parsed", type = "application/json", encoding = "UTF-8")
}
```

to get the duration of the individual journeys. However, I have a much longer list and more destinations. That's why I am looking for a way to make multiple requests in parallel.

Comment: What's worked and hasn't worked? How would you do it iteratively? Provide a minimal *reproducible* example.

Comment: @ Thanks for the comments. I added a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note I did not test this - but first, you would initialize your parallel workers

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(Rcrawler) }) # load required packages onto each parallel worker
```

Make function with your relevant commands

```
custom_parse_json <- function(city) {
    r <- GET(paste0("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=", city, "&to=Zurich&limit=1&fields[]=connections/duration"))
    cont <- content(r, as = "parsed", type = "application/json", encoding = "UTF-8")
    return(cont)
}
```

Export function to each parallel work

```
clusterExport(cl, c("custom_parse_json"))
```

Loop through list of cities

```
parLapply(cl, list_cities, function(i) custom_parse_json(i))
```

This should return a list of your JSON content.

Comment: @ CPak Thanks a lot - works perfect and reduced my parsing time by 75%.